# How can I insert <td> element in a specific column of HTML table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I would like insert dynamically a element in a specific column of HTML table with dataBase data. The table has item's names as the headers and item's properties as the first column. I wont insert the value of property in each item's name column so I wont insert the property value in a corresponding cell. Firstly, I inserted the element and the first column with the properties, now I had to insert the values in each corresponding cell. I am using JavaScript and jQuery.

This is the code that I used to insert the headers and the first column:

```
table.append("<tr id=first><th>"+"    "+"</th>");       
    var items = eval('('+ response + ')');
        for(var i = 0, len = items.length; i < len; ++i) {
            table.find('#first').append("<th id="+items[i]+">"+items[i]+"</th>");           
        }
    });
    table.append("</tr>");
    self.port.emit('getDimension');
        self.port.on('dimension', function(response) {
            var dimensions = eval('('+ response + ')');
            for(var i = 0, len = dimensions.length; i < len; ++i) {
                table.append("<tr id=dimension"+i+"><td>"+dimensions[i]+"</td><tr>");
                items.forEach(function(item) {
                    if(item.dimension == dimensions[i]) {
                        //HERE I NEED TO INSERT THE CELL IN A COLUMN CORRESPONDING ON A ITEM
                    }
```

How can I do this? How can I select the correct cell?

Comment: Using jQuery you don't insert text but DOM nodes, you can't insert open 'tr' insert something and then close it.

Comment: Did you ask this a while ago, then removed the question, and now coming back with the same question?